# Impossible pattern in writing implicit proof object in coq

Tags: coq

I trying to use coq as a programming language with dependent type. I created the following small program:

```
Inductive Good : list nat -> Set := 
  | GoodNonEmpty : forall h t, Good (h :: t).

Definition get_first(l : list nat)(good : Good l) : nat := 
  match l with
    | h :: t => h
    | nil => 
      match good with 
      end
  end.
```

I defined a type for non empty list and create a function which gets the first element of such a list provided there's a proof that it's not empty. I handle well the case where head items consists of two items, but I can't handle the impossible case of empty list. How can I do this in coq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it that is simpler than your try is:

```
Definition get_first (l : list nat) (good : Good l) : nat :=
  match good with
  | GoodNonEmpty h _ => h
  end.
```

Here is a way to do it in the way you wanted to do it. You'll notice it is very verbose to prove that "Good nil" does not exist, inlined.

```
Definition get_first (l : list nat) (good : Good l) : nat :=
  (
    match l as l' return (Good l' -> nat) with
    | nil =>
      fun (goodnil : Good nil) =>
        (
          match goodnil in (Good l'') return (nil = l'' -> nat) with
          | GoodNonEmpty h t =>
            fun H => False_rect _ (nil_cons H)
          end
        )
        (@eq_refl _ nil)
    | h :: _ => fun _ => h
    end
  ) good.
```

You can surely define some of that outside and reuse it. I am not aware of the best practices though. Maybe someone can come with a shorter way to do the same thing.

---

EDIT:

By the way, you can get to pretty much the same result, in a much easier way, in proof mode:

```
Definition get_first' (l : list nat) (good : Good l) : nat.
Proof.
  destruct l. inversion good. exact n.
Defined.
```

You can then:

```
Print get_first'.
```

To see how Coq defines it. However, for more involved things, you might be better off following what gdsfhl from the #coq IRC channel proposed as a solution:

http://paste.in.ua/4782/

You can see that he uses the `refine` tactic to provide part of the skeleton of the term to write, and defer the missing proofs.